# php/mysql trying to output a single result in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter, view

I am new to codeigniter and trying to get a percentage result outputted into the view of codeigntier for my project. Once I fix this, things will be much smoother. 
He is the model function:

```
<?php

public function _construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function percent_specilation1($numstudent)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Student.JRNOption ='1'");

    $numstudent = $query->num_rows()/25; 

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $numstudent;
    }
    return null; 
}

?>
```

Here is the controller.

```
<?php
class Statscontroller extends CI_Controller {
public function _contruct(){
    parent::_construct();
    $this->load->model('Stats_model');
}
public function index(){

    //echo "Various stats for the Journalism department:";
    $data['Test'] = $this->Stats_model->percent_specilation1($numstudent);
  }
   public function view($page = 'Statsview')
      {
            if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
            {
                    // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                    show_404();
            }

            //$data['title'] = ucfirst($page); 

           $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
   $this->load->view('Statscontroller/index',$data);
   $this->load->view('templates/header');
    }
 ?>

  Here is the view
   <html>
   <h1> Various Statistics for the Journalism department</h1>

   <?php
  echo "Percent of students that are undecided:";   
  echo $Test; ?>
   </html>
```

What am I doing wrong? I been trying to get it right for over an hour and I just want to output the single result from the database query. Any help you can provide would be great.. please be respectful. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors

Comment: Problem can be in your index, before and add $this->view() to show your view created.

Comment: models are not looking like CI at all. You probably misunderstood the framework. Please go through documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I have updated some of code of controller and model and use primary key of `student` table for `student_id` in model query.

**Update Model:**

```
<?php

public function _construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function percent_specilation1()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(s2.student_id) 
            FROM Student s2
            WHERE s2.JRNOption='1')*100/COUNT(s1.student_id) AS percentage
            FROM Student s1");

    $result = $query->row_array(); 

    return $result['percentage']; 
}

?>
```

**Updated controller:**

```
<?php
class Statscontroller extends CI_Controller {
    public function _contruct(){
        parent::_construct();
        $this->load->model('Stats_model');
    }
    public function index(){

        //echo "Various stats for the Journalism department:";
        $data['Test'] = $this->Stats_model->percent_specilation1();
        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('Statscontroller/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
    }


}
?>
```

Hope this will help you.